# how to handle memory leaks in amazon web services t1.micro?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a t1.micro instance in amazon web services to handle a virtual image (in concrete a formhub image) and sometimes I got an eror of not allocated memory, I solve it rebooting the instance. Any clues?

is possible to reboot the instances automatically every day?

Comment: it is a linux machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The micro instances are quite constrained with only 600mb or so of RAM. You may solve the problem by moving up to a small or medium instance or even one of the new T2 instances - even the smallest one has 1Gb of RAM.

If this is not an option for you, you can add a cron job to restart the instance at a particular time of day.

ssh in to the instance and type the command:

`sudo crontab -e`

Enter a line like:

`0  5   *   *   *   /sbin/reboot`

to restart the system at 5am each day. This is for an Ubuntu system - the reboot command may be elsewhere in other distributions. Run the command `which reboot` to check.